# Elastic Search map property with diferent types

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

```
public class Document {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DocumentAttribute[] Attributes {get;set;}
}

public class DocumentAttribute {
    public Guid AttributeId {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public object Value {get;set;}
}
```

The DocumentAttribute.Type contains the type of the value (string, date,...)

I can map it like this:

```
.Map<DocumentDto>(
                m=>m
                .Properties(p => p
                .Text(s => s.Name(DocumentDto.DefaultAttributes.Name))
                .Nested<DocumentAttribute>(da => da
                    .Name(DocumentDto.DefaultAttributes.Attributes)
                    .Properties(dap => dap
                        .Text(s => s.Name(n => n.AttributeId))
                        .Nested<object>(dav => dav.Name(n => n.Value))
                        )
                    )
                )
                );
```

If I try to index a document that contains the attributes of multiple types (one being a date) I get:

```
mapper cannot be changed from type [date] to [text]
```

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms what you are trying to do is to dynamically map 2 fields having same name with different types.

**Below is an equivalent ES mapping command:**

```
PUT documents
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "key1":{
        "type": "text" 
      },
      "key1":{
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query Result:** The given query will result in an exception => "Duplicate field 'name'".

**However:**

```
POST documents/_doc
{
  "key1":1 //<======== (Success) value is an Integer
}

POST documents/_doc
{
  "key1":"1" //<==== (Success) Value is a String but can be converted to integer just fine
}

POST documents/_doc
{
  "key1":"Hello" //<==== (Fail) Value is a String but can't be converted to an integer
}
```

**Solution:** Follow below schema for document attributes so that same-named keys need not be tried to dynamically mapped to different types.

```
   {
    "type":"" // <==== e.g Possible values are int, text, date 
    "val_int":1, // <==== here keyname is val_<typeValue>
    "val_text":"Hey",
    "val_date":"2020-01-01" 
   }
```

Comment: That was going to be my next try if no one else has a batter idea